# ExpressionPlayer does not play Azure Smooth Streaming Source

Tags: c#, azure, smooth-streaming-player, azure-media-services

I'm writing a VOD solution. For some time I have been working with the SSME:SmoothStreamingMediaElement successfully for testing and now I would like to utilise one of the Expression Players.

I'm using Azure Media Services, specifically Smooth Streaming. While these work fine in SSME I can't get them to work with an ExpressionPlayer. I don't know why.

I'm now at a point where I'm hard coding a Uri to try and get this to work as below:

```
void dataConectorPopulatePlaylistDownloadComplete(MemoryStream returnData, EventArgs e)
            {                   
<snip>                            
        var myPlaylist = new ExpressionMediaPlayer.Playlist();
        var playlistItem = new PlaylistItem();
        playlistItem.MediaSource = new Uri("http://xxxxxms1.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/b78750fc-9e2f-448c-86e3-d5de084791ea/GOPR0009.MP4-b2d2b578-3560-42c6-9927-2a791f395e19.ism/manifest",UriKind.Absolute);
        playlistItem.IsAdaptiveStreaming = true;
        myPlaylist.Items.Add(playlistItem);
        SmoothPlayerStreaming.Playlist = myPlaylist;          

 <snip>

            }
```

Using the above returns 404 not found in the player video playback window.

This is a valid URL and a valid Smooth Streaming Uri. Using this exact same Uri in a SSME control works fine.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: corrected code as I pasted the wrong extract.

Comment: Do you have the file `/ClientBin/SmoothStreaming.xap`? The ExpressionMedia player makes a request to this file and I think it can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ExpressionMediaPlayer` class makes a hidden call to the `ClientBin/SmoothStreaming.xap` file. If you don't have it there - you should add it.

[image: A request to the SmoothStreaming.xap file]

Here is [the link to the blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/randyoakley/archive/2011/06/24/expression-encoder-4-sp1-silverlight-default-player-template-with-set-audio-volume-on-start-up-feature.aspx) where you can download the xap file and source code of the expression player. [Direct link](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-17-89-08/EE4SP1SilverlightDefaultWithAudioVolume.zip)

After you download the archive above, you can find this file at this path: `EE4SP1SilverlightDefaultWithAudioVolume.zip\Templates\Silverlight Default -- with Audio Volume On Start\SmoothStreaming.xap`

If it still doesn't work, you should replace the `MediaPlayer.dll` by projects from the archive. You need to add (Add -> Existing Project) 3 projects from the `SharedV4SP1` folder: `MediaPlayer`, `OfflineShared`, `PlugInMSSCtrl`.

[image: Solution structure]

I've already tested your code in my application and it started to work after I have copied the xap file and replaced the dll-reference by existing projects.